# Why does SQL LEN function return '1' for a string with several characters?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Simple question - why when I print the value of the `@len` variable in the query below would I be getting the value 1, instead of 12 (the number of characters in the specified string)?

```
DECLARE @string varchar
DECLARE @index int
DECLARE @len int
DECLARE @char char(1)
SET @string = 'content loop'
SET @index = 1
SET @len= LEN(@string)

print @len
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your declaration of `@string` is wrong.  You have no length on the `varchar`.

Try this:

```
declare @string varchar(255);   -- or whatever
```

You just learned that the default in this situation is 1.

This is clearly specified in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx).  As a further note, MS SQL seems to make this rather complicated:

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using
>   the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

The right habit is to always include the length when using `varchar` or `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the variable @string an actual length.  Print the variable @string and it will probably return 'C'.

Answer (score 2):

Becvause `varChar` without a length specification is taken as `varChar(1)`

replace `varchar`  with `varChar(30)` or `varChar(max)`